# How to run a script when a particular element is loaded?

Tags: jquery, aem

I've got this html markup `<h1 id="cruiseWishlist"> Wishlist </h1>` and a script to run when the element is loaded as,

```
$("#cruiseWishlist").ready(function() {

//AJAX call

});

Edit: $("#cruiseWishlist").ready(function() simply listen for a regular document ready. It doesn't matter what selector is used.
```

The `ready()` function is not working here. I tried it with couple of other variations.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready1" );
});

***Result: No console output***
```

---

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
   console.log( "ready2" );
});

***Result: Console resulted 'ready2'***
```

---

```
document.getElementById("cruiseWishlist").addEventListener("onload", function() {
console.log( "ready3" );
});

***Result: No console output***
```

---

```
$("#cruiseWishlist").on("load", function () {
   console.log("ready4");
});

***Result: No console output***
```

Also tried whether the jquery was working. And yeah it was just fine.

```
console.log($("#cruiseWishlist"));

***Result: jQuery.fn.init [h1#cruiseWishlist, context: document, selector: "#cruiseWishlist"]***
```

Edit: `ready()` was not firing because of an error as one of the `ready()` didn't resolved, which fired before on page load, and got queued in the readyList.

Comment: Are you suggesting the ```onload=someFunction()``` in the markup. That too didnt work for me.

Comment: `.ready()` only applies to the entire document, there's no ready event for specific elements. jQuery treats `$(anything).ready()` as equivalent to `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Try doing `alert($)` right before calling `$(document).ready(....)`. If it shows `undefined` then your jQuery has not yet been loaded when you are trying to use it.

Comment: Sounds quite odd if `$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready1" );
});` doesn't result in anything, but a `DOMContentLoaded` listener works, are you sure the `$(document).ready` callback isn't running?

Comment: Also, there's no `load` event for elements that are loaded directly from the HTML . That event only exists for elements that get their data externally, like `<img>` and `<script>`. You can't listen for a `load` event on `<h1>`.

Comment: @PeterB
The result of alert($)

```ƒ ( selector, context ) {

  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
  return new jQ…```

Comment: The last console.log also shows that jQuery is loaded. Are there any errors in the JS console?

Comment: Unless you've somehow redefined `$.fn.ready`, I don't see any way for it not to work.

Comment: @Barmar It works with ```h1```, and probably with any tags, I did work with that. The problem now is ```ready()``` function is not working at all.

Comment: @Barmar No console errors.

Comment: `addEventListener("onload",` should be `addEventListener("load",`. The `on` prefix is not part of the event name.

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "It works"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204108/discussion-between-barmar-and-jezwin-varghese).

Comment: @Barmar Tried changing ```addEventListener("onload",``` to ```addEventListener("load",```. Still no hope.